# How Apple IAP Auto-renewable multiple subscriptions for same product works?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

In my iOS app I have implemented an Auto-renewable subscription for one year. Let's say a user purchased a subscription one month ago, which will end after 11 months. At this time if the user purchase again he is getting the subscription for the next 12 months which I wanted to have for 11 + 12 = 23 months.

I was wondering:

1. Is it a limitation or a basic workflow of the category "Auto-renewable" product of Apple IAP.
2. Which category I should use to accomplish such type of subscriptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An auto-renewing subscription is either active or it isn't.

Once a user has purchased it, the subscription will renew automatically at the end of the current period unless they cancel the automatic renewal.

If they do cancel the renewal, then once that subscription period is up they can re-activate it by "purchasing" the subscription again.

It isn't possible to "stack" auto-renewing subscription IAPs.

If you use a non-auto renewing IAP then it is up to you to calculate the validity period for the users subscription.  If they purchase another 12 months while the current 12 month subscription is active then you can add those periods together.